# Error when trying to install package in R: 'No such file or directory'

Tags: r, package

When trying to install a package in RStudio created by my university, I get the following error message:

```
* installing *source* package 'namePackage' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
```

> Fatal error: cannot open file 'C:\Users\firstName': No such file or directory

My working directory is set to `'C:\Users\firstName lastName\Documents\Case Econometrics\Input'`,
and the package I am trying to install using the command

```
 install.packages("namePackage.tar.gz", source = TRUE, repos = NULL)
```

is in the 'Input' directory.

Is there anyone who knows why it doesn't work to install the package?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you certain the path exists? Also try using `type="source"` for `source=TRUE`. What language is the package written in?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the path exists and is correct. Also changing source = TRUE to type = "source" doesn't seem to solve the problem. The package is written in Dutch or in English

Comment: Sorry I meant programming language. In other words, does it need compilation?

Comment: I don't have any further information on the package itself, the package was just shared to install it on our own.

Answer (score 0):

try this below. I think your slashes are wrong. you should use forward slashes.

```
install.packages('C:/Users/firstName lastName/Documents/Case Econometrics/Input/namePackage.tar.gz', type="source", repos = NULL)
```

Comment: Since I am a Windows user, I have to use \\ rather than /. I did try it anyway, but it didn't work out...

Comment: I work on linux and windows "/" works on both. The issue seems like permission issue. Try moving package to "C:/yourFolder" and try it again.

Comment: Also try with a folder name that does not have spaces.